# Checker board squashed in FF, not Chrome

Tags: html, css

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/Gs32R/)

The empty tiles in the middle are squashed in FF, but not in Chrome. What's the best way to fix this?

### Firefox

[image]

### Chrome

[image]

Comment: CSS3 checkerboard fun: http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/tests/css3select.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
td:empty { height: 50px; }
```

Comment: fixes it in FF, breaks it in Chrome (to tall with padding)....but now that I think about it, I could remove the padding then. **edit:** yep. with padding:0 it works in both.

Comment: @Mark To include or ignore padding in widths and heights you could also [try `box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing).

Comment: Nice!! Didn't know about that property. I actually like IE's box model, but it's not standard. I always want to add padding to the inside, but then everything gets wider, so you have to subtract it off every time you make an adjustment....